# Space of closed parametric curve is a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have a problem that I need help to prove, can anyone please suggest any proof?

Suppose we have, closed parametric curve $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))'$ for $t\in (0,2\pi)$ (here, map is $f:(0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$). How to prove that collection(space) of all such curves is a manifold?

Comment: Your prime is transposition?

Comment: Is a infinite-dimensional manifold. See, for example, The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis (http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf).

Comment: Yes, prime is transposition.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla thanks for the reference.